# How do I insert something in text using sed command (Linux)?

Tags: linux, sed

I would like to **insert** before every `*` character the word `HELLO`.

The following line only **replaces** the `*` with `HELLO`:

```
sed 's/[*]/HELLO/g'
```

What should I do?

Comment: IIUC, you should use : `sed 's/^/HELLO/g'`

Comment: @Jona this places the `HELLO` at the beginning of the string, not before the `"`

Comment: Then, it can simply be : `sed 's/"/HELLO"/g'`

Comment: If you question is about the asterisk, this can be used : sed 's/*/HELLO*/g'

Comment: If you want to add HELLO before a quoted text : `sed "s/'.*'/HELLO&/g"`